Inequality question with constraints, do you know how to go about this?
I am trying to show this inequality:
$$a + m \cdot (1-a) \cdot b \leq c + m \cdot (1-c) \cdot d$$
where a, b, c, d, and m $\in [0,1]$, with the additional conditions $a\leq c$ and $b \leq d$. I was having trouble because I can't simply remove the a and c terms and divide (otherwise there is a contradiction with the constraint $a \leq c$. Please let me know what you think and thank you for your time. Elmina

$a+m(1-a)b =a(1-mb)+mb\le c(1-mb)+mb=c+mb(1-c)\le c+md(1-c)$.

Thanks so much! I appreciate your help!
